# Adding standalone apps to Windows 10 search in Start Menu

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-search

I have a folder C:/bin that contains executables of a few open source programs that are only distributed in such a way.

I like the fact that in Windows 10 I can push the windows key and then start typing to launch apps fast, however it only works for apps that are installed.
How can I make this search index my apps in C:/bin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't directly make it search your `C:\bin\` folder for executables (In fact, executables don't actually ever directly get added to the Windows 10 Start Menu search you're referring to).

You can, however, create shortcuts to each tool with the same name, and place them in a folder within `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` (Just your user) or `%PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` (All Users), ideally within the `Programs` folder here. These will then be added to your Start Menu and indexed for you to search.

Comment: @MarcinLawniczak No problem, I just thought, the path I provided would only add the shortcut for your user account. In case you want it for all user accounts too, I've provided that path also :)